# Cant Delete All rows in Excel through Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

Im having a bit of trouble deleting certain rows in excel using PowerShell, currently I have deleted certain columns that have their header containing a certain word(which for some reason didn't work completely as I intended but I made allowances to make it work) and now I have to delete all the rows in the excel file past a certain point, I have tried numerous methods and none of them seem to work, almost everything that is commented out is a previous try that didn't work, if anyone has any possible tips or solutions I would really love the help.
Here is my code below.

```
#list of columns wanted
$want_list = ("CustomerCompanyName","InvoiceNumber","ChargeStartDate","ChargeEndDate",
"SubscriptionId","ServiceName","ServiceType","ResourceName","Region","ConsumedQuantity",
"IncludedQuantity","OverageQuantity","ListPrice","PretaxCharges","ChargeType","DomainName")
$bad_list = ("PartnerId","PartnerName","PartnerBillableAccountId","MpnId","SubscriptionName",
"SubscriptionDescription","OrderId","ResourceGuid","Sku","DetailLineItemId","TaxAmount",
"PostTaxTotal","Currency","PretaxEffectiveRate","PostTaxEffectiveRate","CustomerId")

 $file = Read-Host "Enter Billing Info Location: example C:\Users\tyarn\Desktop\Billing_Folder\Billing_Info.csv"
    #create new object
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excel.visible = $false

    #open csv file
    $workbook = $excel.WorkBooks.open($file)
    $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1)

    #get num columns
    $num_cols = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count



    #for loop with deleting entire column if name of column isnt in list
    For($i=1;$i -lt $num_cols;$i++){
        if($sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).Text -notin $want_list){[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).EntireColumn.Delete()}
        if($sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).Text -in $bad_list){[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).EntireColumn.Delete()}
        if($sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).Text -eq "OrderId"){[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).EntireColumn.Delete()}
        if($sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).Text -eq "Currency"){[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).EntireColumn.Delete()}
        if($sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).Text -eq "PretaxEffectiveRate"){[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).EntireColumn.Delete()}
        if($sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).Text -eq "PartnerId"){[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(2,$i).EntireColumn.Delete()}
    }
    ##Regular for loop going through and deleteing every row after a certain point doesnt work
    #get number of rows
    $num_rows = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    #doesnt work yet
    #loop deleting unneeded rows
    #$truth_value = 0
    #For($i = 1; $i -lt $num_rows+1;$i++){
    #if($sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Text -eq ""){
    #$truth_value = 1
    #For($j = $i;$j-lt $num_rows; $j++){
    #[void]$sheet.Cells.Item($j,1).EntireRow.Delete()}
    #}
    #if($truth_value -eq 1){break}
    #} 

    #new try
    ##find row to start delete on
    $row_start = $null
    For($j=1;$j -lt $num_rows;$j++){
        if($sheet.Cells.Item($j,1).Text -eq "Daily Usage"){
            $row_start = $j
            $start_delete = $row_start


        }
    }
    ##deleting row 56 everytime cause it moves up one when its deleted? doesnt work dont think
    #For($row_start;$row_start -lt $num_rows; $row_start++){
       # [void]$sheet.Cells.Item($row_start,1).EntireRow.Delete()
        #$start_delete +=1
    #}

    #long solution
    #For($i=1;$i -lt $num_cols;$i++){
       # For($j=$start_delete;$j -lt $num_rows;$j++){
          #  [void]$sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).clear()
       # }
   # }
    ##GET RID OF
    #save
    $file_name = Read-Host "What would you like the new files name to be"
     #must create a folder for this 
    $workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\tyarn\desktop\New_Billing\$file_name")

    #close and release com
    $workbook.Close($true)
    $excel.Quit()
    [void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
    Remove-Variable excel
```

I only included the "bad list" because some columns werent being deleted and for some reason and I only included the other delete column for loops because still some were not being deleted but that is not the main issue, the main issue is that no matter what I try to loop through to delete all the rows after a certain point it wont work, it sometimes one, or half a column off all the rows but never all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there with one of your tries. Use the following code, when $start_delete is known, all the rows from the $start_delete row will be deleted:

`For($j = $start_delete; $j -le $num_rows; $j++){
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item($start_delete,1).EntireRow.Delete()
}`

Importent to use it the `-le`, this will also delete the last row. Using `$start_delete` as indication for the row, will ensure that the same row is deleted each time, because the file is shrinking.

Comment: I tried this, and logically it should work just like a couple of my other tries, but it doesn't, i believe the issue isnt with the code at this point it is with the actual CSV file, because I tried a different approach and tried to export certain columns, and did nothing with the rows, and it did not even export the columns, only the headers which was very strange because i copied the code straight from a reputable source